# Float two classes on opposite sides within a parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float, css-position

I am making a website where I have two ads on opposite sides floating left and right within a parent div. This worked really well until i put in the jQuery for making their positions fixed when scrolling. The left object works just like it should, but the right object suddenly start floating left when scrolling.
What am I doing wrong?

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="left_ad"></div>
 <div class="right_ad"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper{
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px auto;
   display: inline-block;
}
.left_ad{
   width: 135px;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: gray;
   display: inline-block;
}
.right_ad{
   width: 135px;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: gray;
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;
}
```

jQuery (x2, I used the same code for .right_ad as well):

```
<script>
var fixmeTop = $('.left_ad').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
    $('.left_ad').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0',
        left: '0'
    });
} else {
    $('.left_ad').css({
        position: 'static'
    });
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used the same code for the right, did you remember to change the left: '0' to right?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an `if statement` for the `.right_ad` too and use this :

```
$('.right_ad').css({
   position: 'fixed',
   top: '0',
   right: '0'
});
```

Note that the `right : '0'`